# Very large PHP script returns 500 internal server error

Tags: php, cron, http-status-code-500

I am using Cron job to push data to Geckoboard from different applications like - Prosperworks, Chargebee, Intercom. I do this via making API calls to these applications. These scripts are very large since they fetch huge amount of data. So I have set the set_time_limit method to 0 and it works good on local server and when I hit the URL from my Subversion repo.

But when I try to hit the same URL on live server it throws 500 internal server error. I tried to fetch only a few records on live and it worked. But I tried to fetch all records whether in the browser or via cron in returns 500 internal server error for both methods. For sure it has nothing to do with the code because same file works on local server.

I am running cron job from cpanel via wget. URL I am trying to hit is [donesafe.io/geckoboard/partner/new.php](http://donesafe.io/geckoboard/partner/new.php)

Thanks!

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: Memory usage limit? check memory usage and limit in php.ini

Comment: memory_limit is set to 128M in php.ini. Should I increase it?

Comment: @apokryfos - nothing in error logs

Comment: `These scripts are very large since they fetch huge amount of data.` If they fetch huge amount of data, then yes, you probably need to increase the memory limit to allow PHP to have that huge amount of data

Comment: Increased to 512M. Would that be enough? or should I make it 1024M? Edit :- 512M raised same error so going to try 1024M.

Comment: Got same error with 1024M.

Comment: Check the `error_log`. You will see the specific error and can act accordingly. Probably your code iterates through a huge array or something. You might need to consider to do the iteration in batches to keep the memory clean.

Comment: I couldn't find error logs so I created it in public_html and assigned the path to error_log in php.ini but to no avail. Still don't know where to look for errors.